# Pacman board class

Tags: java, pacman

I am trying to make a PacMan game and have not finished yet. So far I have created the code below and there are no errors. However, it is not running. So far I just want the black background screen, walls, and food to show up.

The errors when trying to run the code are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25
at Board.loadBoard(Board.java:92)
at Board.<init>(Board.java:71)
at PacManGUI.<init>(PacManGUI.java:11)
at PacManGame.main(PacManGame.java:8)
```

Please help I am a beginner at coding and don't know why this is happening

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/** 
* This class represents the game board and includes methods to handle 
keyboard events and game actions 
*/

public class Board extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

private static final ImageIcon WALL = new ImageIcon("images 3/StdWall.bmp");

private static final ImageIcon FOOD = new ImageIcon("images 3/StdFood.bmp");

private static final ImageIcon DOOR = new ImageIcon("images 3/Black.bmp");

//Timer for game movement
private Timer gameTimer = new Timer(250, this);

//Timer for PacMan animation
private Timer animateTimer = new Timer(50, this);

//Array to hold the game board characters from the text file
private char[][] maze = new char[25][27];

//Array to hold the game board images
private JLabel[][] cell = new JLabel[25][27];

//PacMan object
private PacMan pacMan;

//Array of Ghost objects
private Ghost[] ghost = new Ghost[3];

//Track amount of food on board
private int pellets=0;

//Track game score (1pt per food item eaten)
private int score=0;

//Steps for animating Pacman's chomp
private int pStep;  


//Construct the game board including the layout, background, PacMan and ghosts 
//and calls the loadBoard method
public Board() {
    //Set the layout (grid), background (black)
    setLayout(new GridLayout (25, 27));
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    //Create PacMan and the ghosts
    pacMan = new PacMan();

    ghost[0] = new Ghost(0); 
    ghost[1] = new Ghost(1); 
    ghost[2] = new Ghost(2); 

    //Load the maze
    loadBoard();


}

//Loads the maze onto the screen from a text file
private void loadBoard() {

    int r = 0;

    Scanner input;

    try {

        input = new Scanner(new File ("maze.txt"));

        while(input.hasNext()) {


            maze[r]= input.nextLine().toCharArray();

            for (int c = 0; c<maze [r].length; c++) {

                cell[r][c] = new JLabel();


                if (maze [r][c] == 'W') {

                    cell[r][c].setIcon(WALL);
                }
                else if (maze[r][c]=='F') {

                    cell[r][c].setIcon(FOOD);
                    pellets++;


                }

                else if (maze[r][c]=='P') {
                    cell[r][c].setIcon(pacMan.getIcon());
                    pacMan.setRow(r);
                    pacMan.setColumn(c);
                    pacMan.setDirection(0);

                }


                else if (maze[r][c]=='0'||maze[r][c]=='1'||maze[r][c]=='2'){
                    int gNum = (int)(maze[r][c])-48;

                    cell[r][c].setIcon(ghost[gNum].getIcon());
                    ghost[gNum].setRow(r);
                    ghost[gNum].setColumn(c);
                }

                else if (maze[r][c]=='D');{
                    cell[r][c].setIcon(DOOR);

                    add(cell[r][c]);
                }
                r++;
            }

            input.close();


        }

    }


    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("File not found");
    }


}




//Open the maze text file for input
//Cycle through all the rows in the maze file reading one row at a time
//Read the next line from the maze file
//For each row cycle through all the columns
//If the symbol is a wall then assign a wall picture to the current square on the screen
//Otherwise if the symbol is a food item then assign a food picture to the current square on the screen and keep track of the number of items
//Otherwise if the symbol is PacMan then assign the closed left image and set PacMan's row, column, and direction (left)
//Otherwise if the symbol is a Ghost then assign the appropriate ghost image and set the ghost's row, column
//Otherwise if the symbol is a door then assign a door 
//Add the current cell to the board panel
//Increment the row
//Close the maze text file




public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


}


public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {


}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {


}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {


}
```

}

Comment: It would help if you could tell us which line is line 92, because that seems to be the line throwing the error. IndexOutOfBounds means you are passing a number into an array as an index that is either negative, or larger than the last index of the array. Remember that the last index is length-1.

Comment: for (int c = 0; c<maze [r].length; c++) { this is line 92